# How set classic ASP on IIS?

Tags: iis, deployment, asp-classic

I have to create site and use classic ASP for it.Actually I'm beginner in ASP.

At first I want to know is it possibale to host ASP on IIS and communicate to WCF coz WCF holds my DB on Entity Framework?

At second I installed IIS Express.msi and IIS Manager with Windows futures help.
I have folder with some pages .asp, I have opened this folder in VS2010 like WebSite.What Else?

What I should to do that this folder has started on IIS, and I could work with this pages?
Thank u!

Comment: Easiest way I know to get started with classic asp on a test pc is Webmatrix: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ I even don't know if it's possible to run classic asp in VS2010, but in Webmatrix (comes with IIS 7.5 I believe) it sure is.

Comment: I can't use webmatrix.But thanks for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check the files if these are running properly or not. It can be run like putting the line "localhost/YourFolderName/Filename.asp" (There must be a folder). The folder must be given full access to the User.

So right click on the folder. Go to the properties/security Tab/click on the edit. Give full access to the administrator or the user as which user you are logged in.